# How to read Azure Blob Url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am creating list of blog posts in react and express/ Azure SQL db. I am able to use the Azure blob storage to store the image associated to the post. I am also able to get the blob url and I am storing that in my SQL db. However when I want to read the url directly it threw an error resource not found. After searching docs and other stackoverflow answers I could infer that it has something to do with SAS token. Can anyone explain what would be the better way to approach this?

https://*yourdomain*.blob.core.windows.net/imagecontainer/*yourimage*.png

Below is the nodejs code.

```
router.post('/image', async function (req, res) {
try {
    console.log(req.files.files.data);
    const blobName = 'test' + uuidv1() + '.png';
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(req.files.files.data, req.files.files.data.length)
    res.send({tempUrl:blockBlobClient.url}); 

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
})
```

Comment: Is your application intended to be a public application? Or do you want to make blobs accessible only on demand e.g. when someone accesses a particular page on your application?

Comment: @GauravMantri I would like to go by the second option, i.e on demand access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However when I want to read the url directly it threw an error
> resource not found.

Most likely you're getting this error because the blob container containing the blob has a `Private` ACL and because of that anonymous access is disabled. To enable anonymous access, please change the blob container's ACL to `Blob` or `Public` and that will solve this problem.

If you can't (or don't want to) change the blob container's ACL, other option would be to create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` on a blob. A SAS essentially gives time and permission bound access to a blob. For your needs, you would need to create a short-lived SAS token with just `Read` permission.

To generate a SAS token, you will need to use `generateBlobSASQueryParameters` method. Once you create a SAS token, you will need to append it to your blob's URL to get a SAS URL.

Here's the sample code to do so. It makes use of [`@azure/storage-blob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) node package.

```
const permissions = new BlobSASPermissions();
permissions.read = true;//Set read permission only.
const currentDateTime = new Date();
const expiryDateTime = new Date(currentDateTime.setMinutes(currentDateTime.getMinutes()+5));//Expire the SAS token in 5 minutes.
var blobSasModel = {
    containerName: 'your-blob-container-name',
    blobName: 'your-blob-name',
    permissions: permissions,
    expiresOn: expiryDateTime
};

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential('your-storage-account-name', 'your-storage-account-key');
const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(blobSasModel, sharedKeyCredential);
const sasUrl = blockBlobClient + "?" + sasToken;//return this SAS URL to the client.
```